# wordcloud: Creating custom colors or changing brightness

Tags: python, nlp, data-visualization, text-mining, word-cloud

I am trying to create custom colors for my word cloud and found the below function in the documentation. But this has hsl values for the single color we choose. As in the official documentation (for grey). 
[image]

```
def grey_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None,
                        **kwargs):
        return ("hsl(200,100%%, %d%%)" % random.randint(49,51))
```

I tried the  changing the colormap parameter, but the colors were too bright.  `wordcloud = WordCloud(width=400, height=175,colormap = "plasma",scale = 2.0, max_words=150,normalize_plurals = False)` How do we define our own choice of colors for the word cloud package or alter color brightness for the colormap parameter.